# Splitting a dataframe with complex numbers into real and imaginary numbers with python

Tags: python, pandas, complex-numbers

I would like to split the following complex dataframe into two columns,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"AB": ['0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i',
                    '0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i',
                    '0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i',
                    '0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i',
                    '0.316227766016838+0.316227766016838i',
                    '0.3162277660168380+.316227766016838i']})
```

I tried in the following way but it works either for - or +

```
df1=df['AB'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)
```

How can I get two new columns for real and imaginary values only? Thanks!

Comment: In last row is typo? Missing `+` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typing mistake. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert values to numpy array with repalce `i` to `j` with casting by `np.complex128` and then get real and imaginary parts to new columns of `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"AB": ['0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i',
                    '0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i',
                    '0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i',
                    '0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i',
                    '0.316227766016838+0.316227766016838i',
                    '0.316227766016838+0.316227766016838i']})

arr = np.complex128(df['AB'].str.replace('i', 'j').to_numpy())
print (arr)
[0.31622777-0.31622777j 0.31622777-0.31622777j 0.31622777-0.31622777j
 0.31622777-0.31622777j 0.31622777+0.31622777j 0.31622777+0.31622777j]

df = df.assign(real = arr.real, imag = arr.imag)
print (df)
                                     AB      real      imag
0  0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i  0.316228 -0.316228
1  0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i  0.316228 -0.316228
2  0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i  0.316228 -0.316228
3  0.316227766016838-0.316227766016838i  0.316228 -0.316228
4  0.316227766016838+0.316227766016838i  0.316228  0.316228
5  0.316227766016838+0.316227766016838i  0.316228  0.316228
```